# How do I send Billing Information to DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

How do I send Docusign account billing information for my customers? They have Docusign account, I do not. I am providing eSigning capabilities on their behalf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Billing REST API](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Billing/) allows you to:

- Retrieve and update billing plan information.
- Retrieve invoices.
- Retrieve and update payment information.